# issue with string codification

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm havin a problem in the way that a string is displayed in the frontend. My string is a html code that I have saved in the database, in the backend (PHP) it's showing well, then, I passed it to the view and I want to show this code inside a textarea but it's printed differently, a portion of what I'm having is this:

```
&lt;script src=&#039;js/socket.io.js&#039;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;                            &lt;script src=&#039;js/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js&#039;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;                            &lt;link href=&#039;styles/style.css&#039; rel=&#039;stylesheet&#039; type=&#039;text/css&#039; /&gt;                            &lt;script&gt;                                // on connection to server, ask for user&#039;s name with an anonymous callback                                $(document).ready(function(){                                    // when the client clicks SEND                                    var toggl=true;                                    var connected=false;                                    var socket;                                    var currentTime;                                    var hours;                                    var minutes;
```

But, what I really want is this:

```
<script src='js/socket.io.js'></script> <script src='js/jQuery-   2.2.0.min.js'></script>

<link href='styles/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> <script> ' $(document).ready(function(){ 
var toggl=true;
var connected=false;
var socket;
var currentTime;
var hours;
var minutes;
```

So, which options do I have to get it in javascript? I mean to say, I don't want to have the tags: &alt,&#039,&gt etc. Thanks before hand!

Comment: Do you want that `<script>`  tag to work or do you want it to be visible on the Client like the `<pre>` tag? The way you're doing it, it won't actually be a `<script>` tag. `html_entity_decode()` would do that in PHP. Of course, I have to wonder why you're storing all that in a database, seems like a waste of space. Databases are for data. HTML is for website structure.

Comment: hey @PHPglue I'll explain, I'm saving it in the database because this is the base code to give to the users, they can configure some things (as CSS appearance, some ips in the js,api key, etc) and I modify this code in the frontend. I'm just saving the    minimin necessary, I know it's a kinda weird but I have my reasons. And yes, the thing is that I want to the user be able to copy and paste this code in their projects

Comment: You could just save the `src` attribute value in the database. To answer your question, though, it really depends on so many things that we don't have enough information to determine the most logical way of doing what you want. If they all have the same images, and can just change the size, maybe vector scaling is the way to go. If they have an account with you (in other words, they have to login) then you may want to use a server language to alter the images, resaving them, using a language like PHP.

Comment: @PHPglue yes, indeed it works in that way, the users have an account and there are saved all the configurables items and I just replace them in the base code. That's working perfectly, the issue I think is when I assign the PHP variable to a JS variable in the front, I had to use `preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $widgetCode->widget_css)` to deal with the linebreaks. I even have a button to generate a file that contains the code, and the file and the content is generated perfectly. Only that I have to make a copy/paste and it's not showing correctly. Thanks anyway